# Getting strange characters when pre-processing text for topic modeling in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, text-processing, data-cleaning

I am preparing the documents for running a `stm` on a large dataframe of news articles in Spanish. When using the function `prepDocuments`, I noticed that the term matrix is getting some strange "vocabs" ("\U0001d45d) as it can be seen in the code below.

**This is my code**

```
#Preparing the documents

out <- prepDocuments(to_stm$documents, to_stm$vocab, to_stm$meta,
                     lower.thresh = 1, upper.thresh = 8677, verbose = TRUE)

#This is what I get when I inspect some of the out$vocab
    > out$vocab[60:95]
 [1] "\U0001d45d\U0001d450\U0001d452\U0001d459\U0001d462\U0001d459\U0001d44e\U0001d45f"    "\U0001d45d\U0001d450\U0001d452\U0001d459\U0001d462\U0001d459\U0001d44e\U0001d45fel"  "\U0001d45d\U0001d452\U0001d45f\U0001d460\U0001d45c\U0001d45b\U0001d44e"     "\U0001d45d\U0001d452\U0001d45f\U0001d460\U0001d45c\U0001d45b\U0001d44e\U0001d460"    "\U0001d45d\U0001d453\U0001d456\U0001d457\U0001d45c"       "\U0001d45d\U0001d456"          "ª"          
 [8] "à"           "a4"          "a6"          "aa"          "aaa"         "aarak"       "ab"         
[15] "abaco"       "abad"        "abadía"      "abajo"       "abalanzó"    "abaleados"   "abanderada" 
[22] "abanderadas" "abanderado"  "abanderados" "abanderar"   "abanderó"    "abandona"    "abandonaba" 
[29] "abandonaban" "abandonada"  "abandonadas" "abandonado"  "abandonados" "abandonamos" "abandonan"  
[36] "abandonando"
```

I have tried to filter or subset these from my dataframe, but I have not been able to find them. Any idea what might be happening? It seems to be related to encoding but I am new to R so I do not really know how the encoding really works.

I am not sharing a sample of my data as the dataframe consists of 17.000 articles so I am not able to guess which ones contain these strange characters.

Comment: You cannot do anything with those non-BMP Unicode code points in R if you are on Windows.

Comment: I am. Not even a chance to convert those unicode to plain character strings to see what are they? If not, do you think that can have an impact on my topic modeling? There are just around 25 terms in that Unicode out of around 50.000 terms in total in the term matrix

Comment: You may filter them out. `grep("[^\\x{0000}-\\x{FFFF}]", out$vocab, invert=TRUE, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I got `integer(0)` as a result. I inspected the `out$vocab[45:66]` where those unicode are and they are still there. Is there any chance I can filter them in my original dataframe? Perhaps using some code to identify the unicode in the news articles?

Comment: Hm, try `out[ with(out, !grepl("[^\\x{0000}-\\x{FFFF}]", vocab, perl=TRUE) ) , ]`, see [demo](https://rextester.com/KAFK57236).

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Comment: For some reason I am getting `incorrect number of dimensions` I saw the demo and it seems to be working

Comment: Then you need to provide an MCVE, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).